# Matplotlib Line Graph with Pandas Pivot Table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, pivot-table

Given the following data frame and resultant pivot table:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'YYYYMM':[201603,201503,201403,201303,201603,201503,201403,201303],
         'Count':[5,6,2,7,4,7,8,9],
         'Group':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B']})
df['YYYYMM']=df['YYYYMM'].astype(str).str[:-2].astype(np.int64)
t=df.pivot_table(df,index=['YYYYMM'],columns=['Group'],aggfunc=np.sum)


    Count
Group   A   B
YYYYMM      
2013    7   9
2014    2   8
2015    6   7
2016    5   4
```

I want to plot it to create a line graph with the y-axis tick labels reflecting the years (YYYYMM) as shown in the pivot table.

Here's what I have so far:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
t.plot(ax=ax)
```

The axis labels should be 2013, 2014, 2015, and 2016, respectively, instead of what is there.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can remove `.astype(np.int64)`but then you get type of values in index `string`:

```
df['YYYYMM']=df['YYYYMM'].astype(str).str[:-2]

print t.index
Index([u'2013', u'2014', u'2015', u'2016'], dtype='object', name=u'YYYYMM')
```

But if you need `int` index, use:

```
from  matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, _: int(x)))
t.plot(ax=ax)
```